# How to make one field's appearance on form depend on another field

Tags: entities

Please I need to create a field whose appearance on my form depends on the field immediately preceding it.

For example in field A the user is asked a true or false/yes or no question. E.g Do you like the English premiership?

If he answers true, a previously hidden field B (which is a taxonomy term)is presented to the user e.g Choose your preferred English Premiership club.

If he answers no, nothing happens.

P.S. Both field will be created via Profile 2 module.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.

Description on module page says -

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between
>   fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for
>   editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the
>   right condition.